# How do we properly insulate a loft ceiling with 2" by 4" without loosing space?

Tags: insulation, roof, attic

We have recently started a home improvement project that involved completely redoing all of our vaulted ceilings. We have a loft area that was about 6 foot in height at the peak. When we did the demo we found that they only used 2"x4" for the roof trusses, and being in NY we cannot get the right r value with out lowering the ceiling and loosing the loft. Any suggestions?

Comment: What R-value are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Code minimum in NY for roof deck/attic floor insulation is R-49.

Comment: Does this renovation legally require you to bring the insulation up to current codes, or are you just trying to do the right thing? You could always add insulation in the 2x4 cavities for now and then add more insulation above the roof sheathing (as @iLikeDirt suggests) whenever you redo the roof.

Answer (score 1):

Let me start by mentioning that you're tempted to skimp out on meeting code for insulation, I wouldn't recommend it. NY gets coooooold! To insulate the roof deck of your vaulted ceilings to code, here's probably your most space-efficient option:

3.5" of closed-cell spray foam between the trusses (R-24) + 5" XPS board **above** the roof sheathing (R-25) + 0.5" drywall covering the spray foam

With this approach, you don't lose any height (assuming there was previously drywall there that you've since removed during the demo). Of course, it will require removing your roofing material to add the foam boards, which is probably going to be a big expensive nightmare if the roof isn't already in need of replacement. Here's probably the next-best option for meeting code and losing as little space as possible:

1. 3.5" of closed-cell spray foam between the trusses (R-24) + 4" Polyiso board on the inside (R-28) + 0.5" drywall covering the foam boards

You lose 4.5" with this approach. Not terrible.

Comment: The double roof (going on top, outside) is the right approach, IMHO. be sure to allow enough space to vent that properly, too.

Comment: For the record, much of New York state requires R-38, not R-49 (although even R-38 won't fit in the 2x4 space). https://energycode.pnl.gov/EnergyCodeReqs/?state=New%20York

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. I was thinking of the 2012 IRC, where they bumped it up to R-49 for zone 5.